# Building table dynamically from code behind, including ASP controls and OnClick and Command Arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I am converting a classic ASP site to .NET website(ASP.Net with C# code behind). I have to keep the same look and feel. So, Lets say I have a section of the page in which I have to list info with no set number of rows (Row example:  Button, Full name, checkbox,  Date of birth). Normally, I would just use a grid view. However, I have to create it with a table structure. The first attempt at this was using an ASP:Panel in the ASP page and using a LiteralControl in the code behind to run the query and parse out the rows, cell, and column date. PanelName.Control.Add(new LiteralControl(HTMLText).
Works great, until I added ASP controls. Apparently, the literal only works with HTML. ASP controls are just not presented on the page. Even if I could produce an ASP:Button, how would I create the On_click method in the code behind or get the Command Argument value ? I have read that you can create and set the attributes of ASP controls in the code behind, but how do I control where it would appear in the ASP:Panel ? There is also the issue of having to generate this in the postback and not-PostBack to keep it populated. Here is an example of what I would typically need to display:

```
              <Table> 
                <tr> 
                 <td>ASP:Button</td>
                 <td>Full Name</td>
                 <td>EmployeeID</td>
                 <td>ASP:Checkbox</td>
                 <td>Date</td>
                </tr>
                  Repeats the <tr>  rows
              </Table>
```

I would need to be able to generate the checkbox and button with a command argument of EmployeeID and also generate the on_click even in the code behind for each generated button.

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Also, I know there are similar posts on this subject, but they just dont answer my question.

Comment: Why GridView Didn't work for you?

Comment: Has to look and feel like the original Classic ASP page. They didn't use Gridviews. They used straight HTML and CSS. Wouldnt look anything like the original page.

Comment: If the original page is in tabular format grid view is the best option. You can have buttons and checkboxes also in the columns. And you can attach commandName and CommandArgument with them. GridView render as a html table. You can always apply CSS on grid view to make it look like whatever you want. Can you share how the original page look like?

Comment: Unfortunately, The code is at work and I am not I am allowed to share. However, My Gridviews look like tabular data and nothing like the table format shown above. How do you make a gridview look like table data?

Comment: GridView by default render as a Table. You might want to read more about how to use GridView. [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=csaspnetgridview) and [here](https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/gridview-example-how-to-use-gridview-in.html) and [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-data-in-GridView-from-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: Going back to the basic Gridview settings instead of reusing one with all kinds of wacky formatting worked for me. Especially removing the gridlines (GridLines="none"). For some reason I cant answer my own question of mark as solved. For that I apologize. Thank You for your help !